# magento - Allow Countries - What does this mean?

Tags: magento, countries

ok... so I feel really stupid asking this question.. but just wondering about the Allow Countries drop down in the admin panel..

What exactly does this mean?

Does it mean that only certain countries are allowed to purchase from your site? if it does mean that how does it determine where you are shopping from? is it done using a IP Geo locator or is it determined when the user inputs their address on the checkout page?

or does it mean that only customers from certain countries have access to the site?

Regards,
Fiona

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's a list of countries you are willing to ship to. [Here's a reference](http://www.indie-it.com/wiki/index.php/Magento) that says this. The available list seems to be [limited by locale](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/43574/), so no geolocating involved. No idea why this is done though.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this feature is so that you can use one Magento website to serve multiple countries with different prices or products. Say you have a German and an English store. You may have different prices and you don't want someone from Germany going to the English store and ordering a product which is not available for Germany or is at a reduced price.

Comment: this is so old... but I need to do exactly this functionality, what you said, and it's not working.

This is my question: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/163839/allow-countries-for-websites-is-not-working